# In Silverlight 4 pass multi sellections from one combobox to stored procedure

Tags: silverlight

I am new on developing an application using Silverlight 4 and VS 2010. I need to select one or multi users from a combobox and pass it(them) as parameter to stored proc. My question is how to send the user IDs collection as parameter to stored proc?

Thanks.

Comment: There's a lot of missing information here. Are you using RIA for your back-end services? Is this a query operation? What do you expect to get back from your SP? We use SP's against Oracle where I work, and we use Silverlight + RIA. Just based on what you've said, I would assume this is a query operation and you're going to return some User objects, in which case I'd probably pass the id's as a List<int>.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes, I use the RIA for the back-end, and SQL server 2005 as database. The combobox is a common control which can let me either select one user or all users from the list. I could select one user from list and click a View button to see all the cases for the user in a datagrid. My problem is how to get the cases for 20 users.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the data to the back-end shouldn't be terribly problematic: RIA Services and WCF know how to take a list (usually an ObservableCollection) and pass it back and forth between the client and middle tiers. If you've been able to pass other sorts of data back and forth between your client and the middle tier, you shouldn't have any difficulty getting this part to work.

The complexity (such as it is) comes when you need to pass the list from the middle tier to the stored procedure. And unfortunately, there isn't any straightforward way to do this. It's one of the great deficiencies in TSQL, in my opinion.

That said, there are a whole bunch of non-straightforward ways to do it. See http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm for some suggestions. All of these require some sort of special handling of the data before you ever get around to calling the sproc, but with some clever LINQ, that can usually be reduced to just a couple lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I updated my SP, and keep working on the SL page and busobj.

Comment: BTW, I see that you've asked two questions that have received solid answers, but you haven't marked either of the answers as "Accepted". It's good etiquette (I know you're a newbie here) to do so - and you'll get better answers in the future if you do :-).